# Propositional logic formula in first order formula?

Tags: propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

Simply put my question is if we can somehow have propositional logic (PL) formulas in a first order predicate logic (FO)formula? I need this to make some connection between the satisfiability of one PL and one FO formulas, so for example if the PL formula is satisfiable, a given signature/interpretation satisfies the FO formula. I'm sorry for not being too specific with the problem, but I'm just looking for some tips and clues, not an actual solution.

Comment: Can't we just add propositional variables to the first order language, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Yes; see van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA57), page 57 : the first-order language is defined with *predicate* symbols $P_i$ of *arity* $r_i$. When $r_i=0$, then $P_i$ is a formula as well as $\bot$.